# Problems with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach

I'm new to javascript and I have problem to iterate a list with javascript.
I need to write the following code with JS:

```
@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, OnlineCarStore.Models.Model>>)ViewBag.TestList)
{
<optgroup label=@item.Key>
  @foreach (var item2 in item.ToList())
 {
    <option value="mercedes">@item2.Name</option>
 }
</optgroup>
}
```

I started to write the code:

```
    $.each(models, function (i, model) {
       $("#models").append
       ('<optgroup label="' + model.Key + '">    </optgroup>');                        });
```

but I keep getting the message, that the model.Key is undifened. 
Can you please help me with this?
 and how can I do this second foreach with JS to work fine..

```
@foreach (var item2 in item.ToList())
 {
    <option>@item2.Name</option>
 }
```

I defined the models list in controller:

```
 var testList = modelRepository.GetModel().Where(m => m.MakeID ==number).GroupBy(m => m.GroupName).ToList();

IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Model>> models = testList;
```

, and I send it with Json to the view like this:

```
 return Json(models, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

As you can see it in this screenshot, the list is not null, and it contains the Key, and it has an elements list that is also not null. 
 The foreach that I write in the view in Razor (I copy pasted in the question) it works fine, but I need this in JS.

[image]
Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

I get this result with console.log(JSON.stringify(models)):

[image]

Comment: Can you log (`console.log(models)`) and show us the structure?

Comment: What is `models`?

Comment: probably `models` is null, or at least not an array of objects all of which contain a `Key` property. How are you defining it?

Comment: Your first code snippet looks like some template engine code. Where is the connection to JavaScript?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: ok, then please show how `models` is getting from the JSON to the JS foreach. Presumably there is an ajax call in there somewhere?

Comment: $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetModels")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#makes").val() },
                success: function (models) {
                    $.each(models, function (i, model) {

Comment: ok then. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(models));` post the result here (into the question, preferably) just to be sure what the data structure is.

Comment: I updated my question. It seems that I don't send the correct list, altought in controller the list is correct as you can see it in the question. You have any ideea why? Thanks for your help!

Comment: in future please paste the actual text not an image, it's harder for others to work with. For instance we can't format it to more easily understand the structure. It's barely readable in the question either. A small sample pasted in would be sufficient. Anyway, it's hard for me to know if that's the "correct" list, since we can't see your class structure on the C# side. What are you expecting? It should be a list of IGroupings I assume - what does that look like?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of basic DOM fragment manipulation/appending, it's a good idea not to do string manipulation and individual appends to the live element; use a document fragment and work with/create document elements. The code's also cleaner, more functional, etc. This uses just JS, no JQuery etc (though that's fine too).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Assumes your model actually has the required methods and properties.
// Tried to more or less approximate your model here
let ViewBag = { TestList : [ { Name : 'TheName_1' }, { Name : 'TheName_2' } ] };
let models = [ 'Mercedes', 'Jaguar' ];

let doc_frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

models.forEach ( model => {
    let optgroup = document.createElement( 'optgroup' );
    optgroup.label = model;

    ViewBag.TestList.forEach ( listItem => {
        let opt = document.createElement ( 'option' );
        opt.value = listItem.Name;
        opt.innerText = listItem.Name;
        optgroup.append ( opt ); 
    } );

    doc_frag.append ( optgroup );
} );

// Assumes something like <div id="models"></div> exists
let models_elem = document.querySelector ( '#models' );
models_elem.append ( doc_frag );

</script>
```

Outputs (source):

```
<div id="models">
<optgroup label="Mercedes">
<option value="TheName_1">TheName_1</option>
<option value="TheName_2">TheName_2</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Jaguar">
<option value="TheName_1">TheName_1</option>
<option value="TheName_2">TheName_2</option>
</optgroup>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
// your array
var arr = [
 {
   category: 'Cars',
    items: [
     {id: 1,name: 'BMW'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Audi'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Jaguar'}
    ]
  },
  {
   category: 'Bikes',
    items:[
     {id: 1, name: 'Harley' },
      {id: 2, name: 'Yamaha'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Bajaj'}
    ]
  }
];

var elem = "";
// loop  it through
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
 var optionGroup = "<optgroup label="+arr[i].category+">";
  for(var j=0;j<+arr[i].items.length;j++){
   optionGroup += "<option value="+arr[i].items[j].name+">"+arr[i].items[j].name+"</option>" ;
  }
  optionGroup += "</optgroup>"
  elem = elem + optionGroup
}


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = elem;
```

```html
<select id="demo">

</select>
```

You need to loop it through and create the optiongroup then append it to the select